# Algebraic values of sine function

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-numbers

Are there algebraic inputs to the sine function that produce algebraic outputs? Other than zero, that is? This is assuming the sine function in radians.

Comment: No, because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Answer (score 1):

No, if you take an algebraic $x$ such that $sin(x)$ is algebraic, as $cos^2(x) = 1 - sin^2(x)$, $cos(x)$ would also be algebraic, and therefore, $e^{ix}$ would also be algebraic.

Hence we would have $x$ and $e^{ix}$ algebraic, which implies (Lindemann - Weierstrass theorem) that $x = 0$